# Reactjs Bootstrap tab active after page reload. Or how can I save active tabs using react redux on state when page reloading

Tags: react-bootstrap

How can I save current active tabs when page reloading?

```
<Tabs defaultActiveKey="profile" id="uncontrolled-tab-example" className="mb-3">
  <Tab eventKey="home" title="Home">
    <Sonnet />
  </Tab>
  <Tab eventKey="profile" title="Profile">
    <Sonnet />
  </Tab>
  <Tab eventKey="contact" title="Contact" disabled>
    <Sonnet />
  </Tab>
</Tabs>
```

Comment: Typically you would persist the active tab state to localStorage. Is there even any React state involved here with this? This seems more a react-bootstrap issue than plain react. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I got the solution for tab activate even after reloading the page

```
const [key, setKey] = useState("Home");

useEffect(() => {
const getActiveTab = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("activeTab"));
 if (getActiveTab) {
 setKey(getActiveTab);
 }
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
localStorage.setItem("activeTab", JSON.stringify(key));
}, [key]);
```

```
<Tabs
id="controlled-tab-example"
activeKey={key}
onSelect={(k) => setKey(k)}
className="mb-3"
>
<Tab eventKey="home" title="Home">
 <h3>Home</h3>
</Tab>
<Tab eventKey="profile" title="Profile">
 <h3>Profile</h3>    
</Tab>
<Tab eventKey="contact" title="Contact">
  <h3>Contact</h3> 
</Tab>
</Tabs>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
For this is I got the alternate solution, which we can use after the page reload or refreshing the page using navigate from React.Taking the route or the url for which we want to keep the tabs to its default state , here after reloading the page the tab will move the active one with its data:-

  let [showActiveTab, setShowActiveTab] = useState("nav-home");

  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const activeTab = showActiveTab;
  useEffect(() => {
    if (activeTab) {
      navigate("/whatever route you wanna give ");
    }
  }, [activeTab])



<Tabs
id="controlled-tab-example"
className="mb-3"
>
<Tab eventKey="home" title="Home"
onClick={() => setShowActiveTab("nav-home")}>
 <h3>Home</h3>
</Tab>
<Tab eventKey="profile" title="Profile">
 <h3>Profile</h3>    
</Tab>
<Tab eventKey="contact" title="Contact">
  <h3>Contact</h3
</Tab>
</Tabs>
```